# Bad accuracy on predicting user ratings upon his reviews

Tags: python, keras, word-embeddings

I am trying to predict user ratings based on books he rated(ratings range between 1-10). So I encoded the summary of the books and then tried to train the model with the text encoding(practically the matrix). I used CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer to encode the summary of each book. My thought was that if two summaries are similar the user will probably rate them the same. But, unfortunately the accuracy metric and loss return awful results. For example, when I am running the code for 5 epochs:

[image: This are the results when I running the code for 5 epochs]

I believe that until the model creation I am doing fine, but because I am totally new to keras I cannot understand how to build the perfect model. What can I do to improve my model?

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
from keras import models
from keras.layers import Dense
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
sw = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def html_decode(s):
    """
    Returns the ASCII decoded version of the given HTML string. This does
    NOT remove normal HTML tags like <p>.
    """
    htmlCodes = (("'", '&#39;'), ('"', '&quot;'), ('>', '&gt;'), ('<', '&lt;'), ('&', '&amp;'))

    for code in htmlCodes:
        s = s.replace(code[1], code[0])
    return s


def clean_text(sample):
    sample = sample.lower()
    sample = html_decode(sample)
    sample = sample.split()
    sample = [s for s in sample if s not in sw]
    sample = ' '.join(sample)
    return sample

# Import the dataframes
df_books = pd.read_csv(r"BX-Books.csv")
df_reviews = pd.read_csv(r"BX-Book-Ratings.csv")

# Merge the dataframes
df = pd.merge(df_books, df_reviews, on='isbn')

# Keep rows where rating !=0 and for the user with id=98391
df_filtered = df[df['rating'] != 0]
df_filtered_0 = df_filtered[df_filtered['uid'] == 98391]

#Remove stopwords 
df_filtered_0['cleared_summaries'] = df_filtered_0['summary'].apply(clean_text)


corpus = df_filtered_0['cleared_summaries'].values
Y = df_filtered_0['rating'].values

cv = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.6)
tfidf = TfidfTransformer()

X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
X = tfidf.fit_transform(X)

#My model
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu", input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="relu"))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=['accuracy'])

X = csr_matrix.sorted_indices(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=20)
```